# Sending hexadecimal commands to serial port of relay board using bytearray in python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays

I need to send to send hexadecimal commands to serial port of a relay board.

I previously used commands like:

```
relay.write(bytearray([0xFF]))
```

This worked,
but if I want to use a variable like

```
m = 255
```

and

```
relay.write(bytearray([hex (m)]))
```

Its showing error: `string must be of size 1`

Whats the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

In your first snippet, `[0xff]` is a list containing the integer 255 written in hexadecimal form. You could have written `[255]` instead of `[0xff]`, they compile to identical bytecode. So to replace that integer by a variable `m` you can do

```
m = 255
relay.write(bytearray([m]))
```

FWIW, your first snippet could also be written as

```
relay.write(bytearray('\xff'))
```

which initializes the `bytearray` with a hexadecimal string containing a single `ff` byte.

The `bytearray([hex(m)])` won't work because `hex(255)` is a string containing four bytes: `'0xff'`, i.e., the digit `0`, followed by the letters `x`, `f`, and `f`.